# Php isset not working after button click

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason when I click the cancel button it should run through the Cancel isset mysql query but it doesn't. It only passes through the mysql query when I make it a $_GET instead of a $_POST. Not entirely sure whats happening.

```
if(isset($_POST["Cancel"])) {
$sCancel = $dbh->prepare("                             
    UPDATE MaterialOrders                              
    SET `cancelledByUid` = :uid,                       
        `cancelled` = 'true'                           
    WHERE `idMaterialOrders` = :idMaterialOrders       
");                                                    
$sCancel->bindValue(":uid", $_SESSION["uid"]);         
$sCancel->bindValue(":idMaterialOrders", $_GET["oid"]);
if ($sCancel->execute()) {                             
    $sCancel->closeCursor();                           
}
```

}

```
<a href="includes/orderItems.php?Cancel=true&oid=<?php print $_GET['oid']; ?>" class="supplierMaterial" target="_blank"> 
<input type="button" value="Cancel Order" name="Cancel" id="Cancel">
```

Comment: I don't see your form with method=post?

Comment: i think it's because you are not posting the value, no form, you are sending the value through href link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are implementing when a link is clicked, you could only use $_GET because to use it as $_POST, form must be submitted in post method. Please try this,

```
<a href="includes/orderItems.php?Cancel=true&oid=<?php print $_GET['oid']; ?>" class="supplierMaterial" target="_blank"> 
    <input type="button" value="Cancel Order" name="Cancel" id="Cancel">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<form method="post" action="includes/orderItems.php">
<a href="?Cancel=true&oid=<?php print $_GET['oid']; ?>" class="supplierMaterial" target="_blank"> 
<input type="button" value="Cancel Order" name="Cancel" id="Cancel">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```